# How do I name a range in google docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, named-ranges

The Google Apps Script API for Docs has a number of methods defined that work with Named Ranges in Docs. While I am familiar with Named Ranges in Sheets, I cannot find a way to name a range in Docs.

Does anyone know how to name a range using the Docs UI? (obviously one can do so programmatically).

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering about that also, but it looks as if it is not possible to edit or even see named ranges in the docs UI.

Lets hope, this will be changed in the future...

Comment: Not sure why they added an API way of working with Namedranges in GDocs

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/named-ranges